# How to iterate over pairs of files with corresponding names in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a folder with test cases named like `test_1_in`, `test_1_out`, 
`test_2_in`, `test_2_out` etc. I want to write a script, that can test my program with these pairs, I suppose it would do something like this in a loop

```sh
diff <($program < $test_in) <($test_out)
```

So the question is what is the best way to do it in Bash? How to iterate through the pairs of files? And also how to capture exception, that is print some error message if `diff` shows some difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `*_in`, and generate `*_out` using parameter expansions:

```
for test_in in test_*_in; do
  test_out="${test_in%_*}_out"
  if diff <("$program" "$test_in") "$test_out"; then
    echo "$test_in failed."
  fi
done
```